# EWS : Remove EWS Body Text in Appoitnments

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

When I create an appointment through EWS API and add a required attendee, he receives the calendar invitation with body filled with the following even If I keep the agenda/body empty :

[image]

It is weird that EWS/Outlook is preppending its own text. This is making the invitation look ugly. How can I remove this text ?

Comment: Show the code that you create the appointment with

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this as well. From what I can tell, there is no real way to create a Meeting Request without it, which I found pretty baffling. I believe you can work around it with a double-tap by saving the invitations to the Drafts folder instead of sending them, then retrieve them and remove the extra text, then use UpdateItems to save them to the Sent Items folder, which should do the trick. It's cumbersome, but I'm not sure if there is another way. I sure hope there is...